# Big opportunity for BCG.SE? Snipe the recurring threads on BGG and answer them here beautifully?

Tags: discussion

I frequent the Race for the Galaxy and Dominion forums on BGG.

Both have some recurring questions that are often adequately answered, but which still pop up constantly.  Further, every time they are asked, they cause new discussion that says basically the same thing as the previous 10 discussions.  But individual posts are always missing some points, they degenerate into calling the OP a noob, etc.

For example, both [using tokens for goods in RFTG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/619499/tokens-for-goods) and [big money too effective in Dominion](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/622536/age-old-arguement-but-still-new-to-the-game) come up very frequently.

Is it okay to ask these questions here for the sole purpose of trying to produce one beautiful answer?

Answer (score 5):

I think its accepted as good practice to post a question for the sake of posting an answer;  its typically considered "polite" to wait a bit between question-post and answer-post to give others a fair shot at the answer;  but you can certainly post your own, complete, beautiful answer to your own question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think this is a good idea so long as your intent is honorable -- to create the one great canonical answer that everyone can find.

Be sure to give credit and links to sources, of course!

Comment: And don't plagiarize!

Answer (score 3):

I would further suggest that once we've given some reasonable period of time for anyone who's interested to offer their best attempt at consolidating the ample source material and we've separated the best answers with voting we should make the highest ranking answer community wiki.

Also, there's a [Dominion big money](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/681/strategies-to-beat-only-buy-money-players-in-dominion) question that would probably work for one of the two examples you cite.

Answer (score 1):

One similar thing we can do is to make sure we revisit questions and edit them for clarity.

Questions can be edited to be more generic, so that they are worthwhile for a greater number of people.